# cannot find symbol for custom annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I have written a custom annotation as below:

```
package annotation;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface FieldRule {
    String value();
}
```

And then the class to utilize this annotation is:

```
package annotation;

public class ScreeningVO {

    String rrcStatusCode;

    public String getRrcStatusCode() {
        return rrcStatusCode;
    }

    @FieldRule("RRC_RULE")
    public void setRrcStatusCode(String rrcStatusCode) {
        this.rrcStatusCode = rrcStatusCode;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ScreeningVO s = new ScreeningVO();
            s.setRrcStatusCode("Yes");
            System.out.println("Testing Annotation");
    }
}
```

Now when I compile this ScreeningVO compiler throws error:

```
ScreeningVO.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        @FieldRule("RRC_RULE")
         ^
  symbol:   class FieldRule
  location: class ScreeningVO
```

However the annotation is provided and both annotation and ScreeningVO exist in same package.

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Comment: It works fine for me. Have you tried rebuilding/cleaning your project?

Comment: I am using java 8

Comment: I've seen this issue only if you aren't able to compile the file containing the annotation (for example if it hides as FieldRule.aj instead of FieldRule.java)